# Translate the negation of "Every cat whom every dog displeases, displeases some dog"

Tags: solution-verification, predicate-logic

Let $D(x) :=$ "$x$ is a dog", $C(x) :=$ "$x$ is a cat", and $F(x,y) :=$ "$x$ displeases $y$".

I proceeded as follows:

$\forall x(x \text{ is a cat and every dog } y \text{ displeases } x \rightarrow x \text{ displeases some dog } w)$.

At first, I was in doubt about the "every" in the antecedent. I thought it might meant "some", if that makes sense at all. I'm not a native english speaker, so I was afraid I may misinterpreted something. Nevertheless, I arrived at the following:

$\forall x [C(x) \land \forall y (D(y) \rightarrow F(y,x)) \rightarrow \exists w (D(w) \land F(x,w))]$,

so that the negation is

$\exists x [C(x) \land \forall y (D(y) \rightarrow F(y,x)) \land \forall w (D(w) \rightarrow \lnot F(x,w))]$.

Thoughts?

Comment: Personally I would have used the $\lnot D(w) \lor \lnot F(x,y)$ formulation in the end just as that "feels" more natural as the negation of an and to me, but its completely equivalent!

Comment: There is an ambiguity of English  grammar in this quote. One meaning is that the cat causes a lack of pleasure in every dog. The other meaning is that every dog causes a lack of pleasure in the cat. Part of the problem is the paucity of puctuation

Comment: @WillJagy Actually, the original quote didn't have a comma. I thought that adding it would make the meaning clearer. Additionally, I had to translate the quote from my native language (portuguese) to english, but I believe there was no loss of meaning. Do you think the comma makes any difference?

Comment: Lucas, I encourage you to write down somewhere, phrases about just one cat:  in modern  Portuguese, a phrase or sentence that says (1): that the cat annoys every dog it meets, or (2): every dog that meets the cat annoys the cat.  Then finish your question for those two possibilities.

Comment: I am a native English speaker. I would express this negation (which you got right, by the way) as: *There is a cat whom every dog displeases, but who displeases no dog.* You could say "and" instead of "but", but that would be less idiomatic. ;/ PS The comma in your (excellent) translation helps any reader parse the sentence and catch their breath after the first clause. In fact, any editor would insist on it. In the negation, the comma before 'but' is less essential but it's preferable, for the same reasons.

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something, but I don’t agree with Will that this sentence is ambiguous. (I am a native speaker of English.) Will’s first interpretation would instead be expressed, “Every cat who displeases every dog displeases some dog.” (This is trivially true, by the way.) The use of “whom” rather than “who,” along with the reshuffling of the word order, has only the second interpretation.

Comment: Just to chime in that I obtained the same negation as you, and that BrianO's and symplectomorphic's points, in particular, echo my thoughts.

Comment: [This related translation question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4198424/21813) came up here recently; compared to your given statement (with that nice comma), this one actually requires more of a judgement call to interpret.